# Google Maps Marker — set background color

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using a transparent PNG as my marker, and would like for the transparent area to be filled a certain color. I previously accomplished this using marker shadows, but those don't work with the visual refresh (i.e. v3.14).

Thanks!

Comment: Make your own custom [Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView).

Comment: @geocodezip I've looked at the docs and the USGS example, but remain unsure how to best implement this approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @geocodezip I've got a 50 point bounty on this question, if you have time for further clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trick could be to manipulate the PNG image with PHP, if this is an option. The following script takes 4 parameters: the image source, the amount of red, green and blue.

**image.php script:**

```
$src = $_GET['src'];

$r = $_GET['r'];
$g = $_GET['g'];
$b = $_GET['b'];

$image = @imagecreatefrompng($src);

// Create a new true color image with the same size
$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);
$color = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

// Fill the new image with desired color
$bg = imagecolorallocate($color, $r, $g, $b);
imagefill($color, 0, 0, $bg);

// Copy original transparent image onto the new image
imagecopy($color, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

// Serve the image
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($color);
imagedestroy($color);
```

**In javascript, call image.php with the desired parameters:**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    map: map,
    icon: 'path/to/image.php?src=http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png&r=100&g=125&b=255'
});
```

**Original image:**

[image: Original image]

**Output image:**

[image: Output image]

Comment: I'm hoping for something Javascript only, but thanks, this is a possibility I guess.

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html it is about creating a marker label (OverlayView) under the marker. Maybe you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, your link provided sufficient inspiration. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `optimized`-option of the marker to false, then you may apply custom css to the marker-img by using the selector:

```
img[src="path/to/custom/marker.png"]
```

### <edit/>

to be able to use the same image with multiple colors simply add the color as URI-fragment, then you will get a unique selector even with the same image:

JS:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  optimized: false,
  icon: 'path/to/custom/marker.png#red'
  //other properties
});
```

CSS:

```
#map-canvas img[src="path/to/custom/marker.png#red"]{
 background-color:red;
}
```

Of course the CSS-rules may also be set dynamically via JS when you don't want to hardcode them, see: [`styleSheet.insertRule()`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmpkap.php)

Demo with multiple background-colors for the same image(including dynamic rule-insertion) :

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/vngp1hdr/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/vngp1hdr/)

Comment: This solution isn't very suitable as multiple markers use the same marker icon.

Comment: Not sure if a version update changed this, but I can't seem to find any img tags with the icon; possibly they are served as background images, so this won't work any more?

Comment: It still works for me, added a demo(note that the `optimized`-option of the markers must be set to `false`).

Answer (score 1):

I think Dr. Molle is right

You simply just apply css to the marker image.

To make the marker not to use canvas, you need to set optimized to false.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
  map: map,
  optimized: false,
  icon: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8w5.png"
});
```

With just css set, you can apply background to all markers.

```
img[src="path/to/custom/marker.png"] {
   background-color: black;
}
```

I am using Tomas example, and modified it

http://jsfiddle.net/Qrj2n/2/

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the quite similar issue. I wish to convert my icon background to to transparent instead.

I believe the easiest way is to convert your existing icon (png,jpg,bitmap) to gif format by making the background transparent. You can use the following [online tool](http://www191.lunapic.com/editor/) to help you do it. It is extremely easy.

The following is the [example of the icon](http://www.penangrealty.my/Property/db924fad-7213-4478-86e2-cc82be1561b9/SR) with transparent output in google map. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

OK, where's the difficulty? If you want the semi-transparent colors, just create then in the icon, like here I have 50% transparent green:

[image]

And then put it on the map:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qrj2n/

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      map: map,
      icon: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8w5.png"
});
```

Comment: I want to set the background color *of the marker*, not of the icon. That way, I don't have to create an icon for every hex color that exists.

Comment: @mustafa.0x then you should be more clear in your question. You wrote *"I'm using a transparent PNG as my marker, and would like for the transparent area to be filled a certain color" - which suggest you are talking about transparent area of the PNG! Sorry but then its a poorly written question. You should describe what you want and why, we are not here to guess your mind.

Comment: Haha, cheeky, aren't you? :) I didn't downvote you; no need to be snarky.

Comment: @mustafa.0x I know it wasn't you :) It's not a revenge. It's that I just really think that your question is poorly written. BTW my answer would be a solution to the question as you wrote it.