# Google Maps custom marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to create a custom marker that would be similar to the look of the ClusterMarker.
I want to display the number of markers each County has.
That mark will display in the centre of the County showing the number of markers.

How would I create the marker to display the number in the middle of it.
This number would be queried from the database.
They don't need to be clickable.

Thanks

Comment: You can manipulate the image with PHP. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20778505/1238965) and other PHP image processing functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var count = markers[i].getAttribute("count");

    if (count == '') {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('modules/mod_boutiques_map/images/mm_20_blue.png', iconSize, null, iconAnchor);
    } else if (count < 10) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.4|0|FFFF00|9|_|"+count, null, new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
    } else if (count < 99) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.46|0|FFFF00|10|_|"+count, null, new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
    } else {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.54|0|FFFF00|10|_|"+count, null, new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be mad to calculate center of each country each time and, *I bet, countries limits won't change so often* to generate a tedious maintenance, so, as long as you will retrieve the data of the number of markers for each country, I think **your best option will be to store the countries' centers** custom marker's position in database, in a file or in a constant class... depends of how you develop your map.

To customize markers with special icons, hide the close button, change color, and put detailed info inside follow steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers).

After creating a custom marker layout, and fetching data of the markers, you just have to create an array of markers and insert there all customized markers.