# Google Maps API - Why don't labels animate along with markers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a Google Map and added a few markers to it. Each marker has a one-letter label ("A", "B", "C"). I then animate each marker to bounce.

That all works fine with one annoying exception: The labels ("A", "B", "C") don't bounce along with the marker, so it looks odd.

The JS/jQuery is below. [I also have a code pen here showing the issue](http://codepen.io/itsthechad/pen/bVePLJ).

Any suggestions on how to have the labels bounce along with the markers?

```
$(function () {

    var map;
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var labelIndex = 0;
    var markers = [];
    // Map locations
    var mapLocations = [{
        "name": "Windwood Hollow Park",
            "description": "This is the description for location 1",
            "position": {
            "lat": 33.942253,
            "lng": -84.278242
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Peeler Road Linear Park",
            "description": "This is the description for location 2",
            "position": {
            "lat": 33.940143,
            "lng": -84.278394
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Winters Chapel Animal Hospital",
            "description": "This is the description for location 3",
            "position": {
            "lat": 33.940707,
            "lng": -84.272021
        }
    }];

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 33.943345,
            lng: -84.280186
        },
        zoom: 15
    });

    for (var j = 0; j < mapLocations.length; j++) {

        var currentLabel = labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length];

        // Create a map marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapLocations[j].position,
            map: map,
            title: mapLocations[j].name,
            label: currentLabel
        });
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
});
```

Comment: I noticed that as well.  Probably need to open an issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

Comment: Correction.  There is an [open issue ("PendingReview") Issue #8573](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8573) from Sep 6, 2015.

Comment: A "solution" would be to use your own markers with that letter inside it or to create them "on the fly" with a backend image manipulation. Some inspiration here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20778505/1238965

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The labels don't seem to bounce with the marker icons. To achieve bouncy labels I would suggest that you should use marker icons that have the labelled character on the icon itself. [Image Charts api](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons?hl=en)(Deprecated)
 serves dynamic custom icons.

Example of dynamic icon would be: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|FF9900
*where chld=anyletter (here A)
and the last 6 characters are hex color code(here FF9900).*

Deprecated chart api allows to set custom colour and label for the marker. 
New charts api dropped the support for dynamic icons.

Alternatively google also maintains a few custom icons on

> maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png

where *letter* is any alphabet. Eg: http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png

Custom icons are also available with https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/wiki/NumericIcons

**Set the icon property of marker object**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapLocations[j].position,
            map: map,
            title: mapLocations[j].name,
            icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png"
    });
```

[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVgQEz)

Comment: Using Google's pre-labeled icons works for me. Thanks!